# Firebase Realtime Database is sometimes not updated

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have implemented the presence feature by referring to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). However, sometimes the online status caused by onDisconnect is not updated and remains in the Realtime Database.
I haven't been able to identify the problem, but it seems to be happening on Mac / safari and iOS.

```
....

  useEffect(() => {
    const connectedRef = ref(db, '.info/connected');

    const unsubscribe = onValue(connectedRef, async (snap) => {
      if (snap.val() === true) {
        const con = await push(myConnectionsRef);

        await onDisconnect(con).remove();

        await set(con, true);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

....
```

The security rules are as follows, and I don't think it's an issue of not being written to by logging out.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "connections": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try changing the rule to like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "connections": {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

That is, Only user can access if they are logged in.

Comment: Thanks you Eljos.
But I have written the following code before, and even then I had a problem with status remaining.
```
{
  "rules": {
    "connections": {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid":{
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```
The suggestion you gave doesn't seem to be too different from the code above.

Comment: @yyddoi Are you doing the Realtime Database or the Firestore?? The documentation you provided is of the Firestore

Comment: What I want to know is the specification about Realtime database. I'm also using Firestore, so I mistook the documentation. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities) is the documentation for Realtime Database, although the essential implementation is not much different